# Combining Azure Monitor charts from different resources in one chart

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-monitoring

I was wondering if it was possible to combine 3 different metric charts in one chart.

I know this is possible when these are metrcics for 1 resource. but i want to combine 3 metrics charts of 3 resources (one resource type) into 1 chart.

From this

[[image: The picture is for illustration the values are not reel[1]]

To this 
[image: The picture is for illustration the values are not reel]

PS: For extra information , the resource type I want to deploy this for is anaylis service. this is to get a better overview of all resources of analysis service in 1 chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can combine metrics from multiple resources into a single chart.  In the portal, go to the Azure Monitor blade and click on **Metrics**.  From there, you can build a single chart with metrics from multiple resources.

There are other options available too for visualizing your data that include Azure services (ie: Log Analytics, App Insights, etc.) and other 3rd party solutions.  More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualizations?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do this in the default metrics explorer charts, as these only look at a single resource. To look across multiple resources you need to send you metric data into log analytics then use the data explorer to create a query that gets you the data you want and chart that.

Comment: @Rick Rainey's comment did the trick but indeed your solution with sending the data to log analytics would've worked as well I guess. Thnx